# GPS Coordinates Regex and combine them as a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, coordinates

GPS:             48.8896 N - 2.37586 W

GPS:             52.6399 N - -1.1267 W

I have those coordinates data after reading from the HTML File, and I want to have a regex that separate then combine them as a string with a semicolon in the middle like **48.8896;2.37586** or **52.6399;-1.1267** .

How could the pattern be in this case? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where is it failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within given examples:

```
string output = string.Join(";", Regex.Matches("GPS: 48.8896 N - 2.37586 W", @"-?\d+\.\d+")
                                      .OfType<Match>()
                                      .Select(m => m.Value));
```